# PhpStorm Emmet shortcut - Increment/Decrement Number

Tags: phpstorm, keyboard-shortcuts, emmet

```
“Increment by 1” (Ctrl+↑)
“Decrement by 1” (Ctrl+↓)
“Increment by 0.1” (Ctrl+Alt+↑)
“Decrement by 0.1” (Ctrl+Alt+↓)
“Increment by 10” (Shift+Ctrl+↑)
“Decrement by 10” (Shift+Ctrl+↓)
```

http://docs.emmet.io/actions/inc-dec-number/

This shortcut doesn't work on PhpStorm. How can I change Emmet shortcuts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhpStorm does not support that particular Emmet action/feature as it has [own](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-193) Emmet implementation.

Plus, those shortcuts are used by other actions in IDE (and were already in use before Emmet was even created).

Right now you may use **Shifter plugin** -- it can do increment/decrement by 1/10 (or whatever values you will configure it to use).